# OneToMany column returns empty collection

Tags: java, rest, jpa

I'm having trouble retrieving a oneToMany column collection from an entity that I recieved through a request to a restful java client:

```
    Itinerary itinerary = port.checkItinerary_XML(Itinerary.class, from, to);
```

The itinerary object has all its' data retrieved but when I try to retrieve its' OneToMany column I only get an empty collection:

```
    Collection<Route> routeCollection = itinerary.getRouteCollection();
```

I have tried lazy and eager fetchtype but neither worked.

Itinerary entity(relevant parts):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITINERARY")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Itinerary.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Itinerary i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Itinerary.findById", query = "SELECT i FROM Itinerary i WHERE i.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Itinerary.findByStartCity", query = "SELECT i FROM Itinerary i WHERE i.startCity = :startCity"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Itinerary.findByEndCity", query = "SELECT i FROM Itinerary i WHERE i.endCity = :endCity")})
public class Itinerary implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "itineraryId")
private Collection<Route> routeCollection= new ArrayList();

public Itinerary() {
}

public Itinerary(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@XmlTransient
@JsonIgnore
public Collection<Route> getRouteCollection() {
    return routeCollection;
}

public void setRouteCollection(Collection<Route> routeCollection) {
    this.routeCollection = routeCollection;
}
```

Route entity(only relevant parts):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Route.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Route r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Route.findById", query = "SELECT r FROM Route r WHERE r.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Route.findByFromCity", query = "SELECT r FROM Route r WHERE r.fromCity = :fromCity"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Route.findByToCity", query = "SELECT r FROM Route r WHERE r.toCity = :toCity")})
public class Route implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITINERARY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional = false)
    private Itinerary itineraryId;

    public Route() {
    }

    public Route(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public Itinerary getItineraryId() {
        return itineraryId;
    }

    public void setItineraryId(Itinerary itineraryId) {
        this.itineraryId = itineraryId;
    }


}
```

EDIT: Restful Itinerary client that handles checkItinerary_XML call:

```
public class ItineraryClient {
private WebTarget webTarget;
private Client client;
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/id2208_hw3_server/webresources";

public <T> T checkItinerary_XML(Class<T> responseType, String departureCity, String destinationCity) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("checkItinerary/{0}/{1}", new Object[]{departureCity, destinationCity}));
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
}
```

Comment: Well, the getter is annotated with XmlTransient and JsonIgnore, so whether it's serialized to XML or JSON, the marshaller will ignore that collection.

Comment: can you please show us the code where you actually do the retrieval of `  Itinerary itinerary = port.checkItinerary_XML(Itinerary.class, from, to);` and `Collection<Route> routeCollection = itinerary.getRouteCollection();`?

Comment: @JB Nizet I tried removing it but then I got internal server error for the  port.checkItinerary call. How should I approach it?

Comment: @idipous I added the code segment.

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve `itinerary = port.checkItinerary_XML(Itinerary.class, from, to);` in a transactional method and then you try to get the `routeCollection` in a later point outside the transaction you will get an empty collection.

A solution would be to make the call within the transaction used to retrieve the iteneray.

Comment: Something like make a new method in my port object called getItineraryRouteCollection where I first retrieve the itinerary object and then on the retrieved object make the call getRouteCollection and return it?

Comment: I added the code for the Itinerary retrieval in the main post so you can see.

Comment: ok so as to understand. You get the an `Itinerary` object from the web service. Why this POJO should know about the `Route Collection` you define in the database? In other words the `Itenerary` you have is not managed. Correct or do I miss something?